# What is the significance of purple in the dream world of Sally?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, being-human-us

In the dream state of Sally in the [*Being human (US)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Being_Human_%28North_American_TV_series%29) S02E10, when she was controlled by her Reaper self, why was everything purple?

[image: Building in the dream world purple]
[image: Building on the original world with green colour]

Even the green from the building was replaced with purple. And show's title card was altered too

[image: Show's title card]

Building's interior was all black, white and gray to highlight purple more:

[image: Charcters wearing purple shirts]
[image: pic from the show showing purple props]

Even her wardrobe was full of purple except cloths from her dead self:

[image: wardrobe full of purple clothes]

What is the significance of using purple in the dream world?

Comment: I'd fancy a guess, purple (normally a pinker purple) is associated with Lotuses, as in Lotus Eaters from the Odyssey. http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LotusEaterMachine It's partly to foreshadow that it's all just in her head.

Comment: @cde maybe you can make an answer out of it